# html5 time element question

Tags: html

what is the very least date and time I can have for my time element to be machine readable. An example would help very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**The spec**](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/text-level-semantics.html#the-time-element) says this:

> The time element represents either a
>   time on a 24 hour clock, or a precise
>   date in the proleptic Gregorian
>   calendar, optionally with a time and a
>   time-zone offset.

You may ask, "what is the 'proleptic Gregorian calendar'?". I sure did.

[**According to Wikipedia:**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proleptic_Gregorian_calendar)

> The proleptic Gregorian calendar is
>   produced by extending the Gregorian
>   calendar backward to dates preceding
>   **its official introduction in 1582**.

Another informative paragraph from the spec:

> The time element is not intended for
>   encoding times for which a precise
>   date or time cannot be established.
>   For example, it would be inappropriate
>   for encoding times like "one
>   millisecond after the big bang", "the
>   early part of the Jurassic period", or
>   "a winter around 250 BCE".
>
> **For dates before the introduction of
>   the Gregorian calendar, authors are
>   encouraged to not use the time
>   element, or else to be very careful
>   about converting dates and times from
>   the period to the Gregorian calendar.**
>   This is complicated by the manner in
>   which the Gregorian calendar was
>   phased in, which occurred at different
>   times in different countries, ranging
>   from partway through the 16th century
>   all the way to early in the 20th.

So, it looks like the answer is: don't use it for dates before the introduction of the Gregorian calendar, or else be careful about it.

You asked:

> what is the very least date and time I
>   can have for my time element to be
>   machine readable.

It depends on what *machine* is reading it.

For example, a lot of software won't handle dates before [**Unix time**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) *(January 1, 1970)*.